# How can we send message to our linkedin connection using linkedin API

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I use below Code for send message to my linked in connection using linked in API

```
NSString *xml;
xml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <mailbox-item> <recipients> <recipient> <person path='/people/~'/> </recipient> <recipient> <person path=\"/people/%@\" /> </recipient> </recipients> <subject>Congratulations on your new position.</subject> <body>You are certainly the best person for the job!</body> </mailbox-item>",idProfileRequest];
NSLog(@"xml %@",xml);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"]];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url consumer:ApplicationDelegate.consumer token:ApplicationDelegate.accessToken callback:nil signatureProvider:nil];

NSData *myRequestData = [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
OADataFetcher *dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc]init];
[dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(dataPost:didFinish:) didFailSelector:@selector(dataPost:didFail:)];
```

I am using synedra LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client OAuth library.

and I have also same problem for OAuth signature.

401
  1385620251922
  1PLI8KSALM
  0
  [unauthorized]. OAU:x19azkkc5f2p|21d8df03-7529-41c5-af85-81d8a6f3accb|*01|*01:1385620251:WFDMNR7UwlJcEK8inflitVvX+0M=

Comment: I have same problem no one can give answer this question

Comment: Did you find the answer for this issue. Please share if you have.. Thanks